# During scoring, can an Inuksuk be a double?

Tags: scoring, nanuk

In the card game Nanuk, When the game is over and players are tallying up their points, can an Inuksuk be counted as a double card (a card with two animals on it)? Since it's a wild card, an Inuksuk can be used to finish a pair or a set. A double card is a pair on its own. So can an Inuksuk be a double, and hence a solo pair, and thus worth 1 point? Or can it be paired with a double to create 2 pairs and two points?

Answer (score 2):

The rules of Nanuk(you should specify the game you mean somewhere) says Inukshuk cards may be used to "fill any pair or set"(singular) and that only double cards may be used twice. It does not say the inukshuk can BECOME a copy of another card.

I'd say no, they cannot be used in this way.